# clean delete of file in Ubuntu that was deleted while being written to

Tags: linux

I have a bash script that writes to a file like so:

```
doSomething &>"${LOGFILE}";
```

The file got deleted while the script was running; then I learned from https://stackoverflow.com/a/984712
that

> even if you where to delete the file from the directory the program would continue to write data to it (and use up disc space) even though no other program would have any way of referencing it.

The script may have written a large amount of data to the file after the delete;
is there a way to regain access to the new contents to do a clean delete? Or is the space automatically freed up once the script quits?

Comment: Nope. Files are reference-counted. An open file descriptor counts as a reference. As soon as the last reference is gone, the file is gone. There is nothing to clean.

Comment: @n.m. that should be an answer