# What is the simplest way to delete the contents of a file in BASH?

Tags: bash

I need to delete all lines in a file, but leave essentially an empty file with no content and no lines. As best I know, one can do this:

```
rm file.txt 2> /dev/null
touch file.txt
```

However, is there a simpler, more canonical solution in BASH?

Comment: you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980283/truncating-a-file-while-its-being-used-linux (as while a file is opened, it is still accessible even if it's "deleted")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use truncate.

```
truncate -s 0 filename
```

Answer (score 24):

This is a pretty fast way I always use:

```
> file.txt
```

It completely empties the file and updates the modification time.

Comment: I used a slight variation: `true > file.txt`. See this for more information: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2188

Answer (score 6):

Another (brutal) way to empty a file would be the following:

```
cat /dev/null > filename
```