# Read the whole file, then overwrite all in same std::fstream

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, readfile

Although I found a lot of stuff about `std::fstream` on SO, I still can't understand how it operates. Let's see this minimal example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::fstream fs{ "somefile.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::in };
  std::string line;

  while (std::getline(fs, line))
  {
    // reads the whole file
  }

  // the purpose is to overwrite the whole file
  fs.seekp(0, std::ios_base::beg); // moves at the beginning
  fs << "Hello world!" << std::endl; // writes in the file

  // possibly other read/write
}
```

This does not work, it seems that one cannot firstly read, and then write in the same stream according to everything I read about. **I know the workaround that consists in closing the file, then opening it with the `std::ios_base::trunc` flag**. However, that seems to be nonsensical: why is there such a limitation? Cannot we technically just overwrite the file after the reading?

Comment: maybe you need to clear the `eof` bit

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @ForceBru It does not write anything, the modification time of the file does not even change.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's the point, I wanted to flush explicitly.

Comment: The stream gets flushed by its destructor, which runs at the end of the block, immediately after the insertion. Explicit flushing is rarely needed, and it won't fix the problem that's presented here.

Comment: isn't add `fs.clear()` after the `while` loop work?

Comment: @PeteBecker I updated my code. I want a flush because in my actual code, I want to overwrite other times possibly.

Comment: It's not "nonsensical" in the slightest and it is not clear to me why you think that it is. Streams are _flows of data_; truncating a file to nothing is a file-level operation.

Comment: @Arkadiy I read this, but the question is why technically?

Comment: @Boiethios: Because streams are _flows of data_, and truncating a file to nothing is a file-level operation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hum, I think I understand. I saw the fstream like a handler on a file. Why don't you post an answer about it?

Comment: @Boiethios: Because I don't accept the premise of the question :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The *nonsensical* thing? I protected my back by adding "seems". That was a personal feeling.

Comment: Looking for "technical" reason brings us into opinion-based territory. My opinion is that using fstream that way violates "do one thing" rule. But that's just an opinion.

Answer (score 4):

The loop iterates until the fail bit gets set. Just `clear()` the flags prior to the seek:

```
fs.clear();
```

If you only want to overwrite the starting bit that is sufficient. If also want to truncate the stream I'd explicitly `close()` and `open()` it, where the `open()` would not set `std::ios_base::in`.

Comment: Yes, that writes the string, but the whole file is not overwritten.

Comment: @Boiethios: You did not write any code to perform that function. Don't blame fstream for that.

Comment: Why do we need to release the file, then to reopen it? There are operations we do not need normally!

Comment: @Boiethios: until the filesystem libraries are standardized, the only platform independent way to truncate the file is during opening, so there is no workaround.

Comment: @AndyG Oh, thank you! So that's it. Could you explain this as answer?

Comment: _"There are operations we do not need normally!"_ When do you not need them? What is this "normally" of which you speak? Are you confusing streams with containers? Regardless of implementation/POSIX constraints, the two are different kinds of things and file truncation has next to no business existing in the `fstream` interface.

Comment: @Boisthios: there may be OSes which allow truncating an open file. I'm pretty sure not all do. Also, the file stream interface is pretty much unchanged since a fairly long time: I could well imagine that popular systems back then did not have a way to truncate an open file.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I saw that for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980283/truncating-a-file-while-its-being-used-linux

Comment: @Boiethios: which actually does open (and thereby truncate) the file again! Yes, you can open another file stream to truncate the one you have already open. What will happen next is somewhat unclear, though, as the streams are buffered. You may get back some of the buffers, possible preceded by a lot of zero pages (depending on where your file pointer is at this time and how the `std::filebuf` is implemented).

Answer (score 1):

After reading the whole file, the `fs` is now in `eof` state. You need to clear the state so it can do following IO operations.